# Book about an amnesiac protagonist who sucks the life out of anyone nearby if he dies near them

Tags: story-identification, novel, urban-fantasy

A book about an unkillable, amnesiac protagonist that wakes up in the introduction of the book, after being killed in a children's playground, looking up at a fake dragon children's rocking horse. Works for the gangsters but they're actually evil undead things. He keeps a list of all of the names of everyone he's accidentally killed in order to regenerate, meets a short woman with pointed ears, kills gargoyles with her and her undead werewolf friend. There's a vampire named Phillip.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: This may well not be it, but it sounds a bit like the Chronicles of Darkness (formerly New World of Darkness), since not only does it have vampires and werewolves, but the sin-eaters have precisely that power—to come back from the dead at the cost of some nearby person dying.

Comment: Not to mention that it has gargoyles as a sort of vampire bloodline, and lots of supernatural creatures that could have pointed ears, most notably changelings.

Comment: I don't remember anything about the cover, but I read this book a little under ten years ago. Pretty sure it was an early 2000's or 90's publication, the in story references weren't extremely dated or obscure. Oh and as far as I know, the protagonist is the only person to have the resurrection ability.